# Cannot Access my web service in my mobile application when it is not connected in same network?

Tags: android, vb.net, web-services

I developed a windows application using vb.net. and i created a web service and executes some function for my android mobile app access it..  The android app which i created works fine and access my windows web service functions when the mobile connected to system in the same network. i am using system static ip address in my mobile to access my windows application web service. it works fine...

but i give public id address when the mobile is not connected to the same system network, it is not connected to my system web service..
     May i know how to connect my android app and my system when it is in different networks.

I am using the following coding in my windows application to host my web service

```
 webhost = New WebServiceHost(GetType(WebService))  
 webhost = New System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost(GetType(WebService),New Uri("http://localhost:2001/myWebService"))
                webhost.Open()
```

Comment: Have you checked, that your system is reachable from outside the network? Firewall, Routersettings, Port-Forwarding?

Comment: are you sure that your server (your PC) is accessible from the internet? did you forward the ports on your router? Does your ISP provide you with a private IP address?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko accessible from internet means?.. i am connecting my app through wifi in same network.its work fine.. but my aim is to access it without wifi connection to my system.

Comment: @derpirscher how to check this friend?

Comment: `means?` means that you need to make sure that your PC is visible from the internet. : ` did you forward the ports on your router? Does your ISP provide you with a private IP address?`

Comment: How is your server connected to the internet? Do you know the public IP address (ie the one provided by your ISP, be aware this may change from time to time, depending on your service contract). Does your ISP allow to access your machine from the internet? Is your router correctly configured to forward the needed ports to your machine?

Comment: Try to ping your machine. If it fails then things are not set up for internet access.

Comment: @ Vladyslav Matviienko I created port in system. and my service now accessed through internet.. Thank you... friend..

Answer (score -3):

**If both your desktop and phone are connected to the same WiFi** (or any other local network), then use your desktop IP address assigned by the router (not `localhost` and not `127.0.0.1`).